# Unable to create a geometric network in a PostgreSQL Spatial Database Connection

Tags: arcgis-10.0, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, geometric-network

I've created in ArcCatalog a Spatial Database Connection to an PostgreSQL  database server. I've imported there all my data (from a local hard drive) and now I want to edit them. But apparently I cannot build a geometric network, neither a topology in my Feature Dataset.

The error message is like this:

> "Cannot create geometric network. The selected feature dataset does
>   not contain any feature classes which can participate in a new
>   geometric network"

.

This usually happens when you have either a topology or a geometric network, but I have neither.

I use postgreSQL 8.3 /
ArcGIS 10.0 /
ArcSDE for PostgreSQL 10

Comment: Is it because I don't have PostGIS?

Comment: Installed PostGIS meanwhile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem is the fact that I imported my data from my local drive. Somehow the imported data is still connected to the place from where I've imported the data and prevents me from creating a geometric network here. The solution would be to create the data all over again, but this would take ages. So? how can I solve this import thing and be able to create a geometric network in the same time?

Answer (score -1):

Check if the featureclasses are not registered as version.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for helping to answer a question on this site.  It would be helpful if you could add some more detail on how you do this and what it means for Ligia.